# Fix for null is not an object error in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to store a task in asyncstorage but as soon as I enter a character in the `TextInput` I get an `null is not an object (evaluating 'item.reminder_content')` error. I can't seem to find the issue with this and I've been stuck on it for the past few hours, any ideas what I did wrong

```js
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import styles from '../components/Styling/reminder';
import Card from '../components/Card';

import Background from '../components/assets/reminder_back.png';
import back from '../components/assets/arrow_left.png';
import Add from '../components/assets/add.png';

export default class Reminder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reminder_content: '',
      reminders: [],
    };
  }

  Create_Task = async () => {
    let {reminder_content} = this.state;

    if (reminder_content !== '') {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('Reminder', reminder_content);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = async() => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('Reminder').then(value => {
      this.state.reminders.push(value);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ImageBackground source={Background} style={styles.background} />
        <View style={styles.root}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
            <Image source={back} style={styles.back} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Reminders</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={styles.list}>
          {this.state.reminders.map(item => {
            return (
              <Card>
                <Text>{item.reminder_content}</Text>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Create Reminder"
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.reminder_content}
            onChangeText={(reminder_content) => this.setState({reminder_content})}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              source={Add}
              onPress={() => this.Create_Task()}
              style={styles.add}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async Storage can only store string data, so in order to store object data you need to serialize it first. For data that can be serialized to JSON you can use JSON.stringify() when saving the data and JSON.parse() when reading the data.

```
Create_Task = async () => {
    let {reminder_content, reminders} = this.state;

    if (reminder_content !== '') {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('Reminder', JSON.stringify(reminders.concat(reminder_content)));
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = async() => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('Reminder').then(value => {
      const newValue=JSON.parse(value);
      this.setState({reminders:reminders.concat(newValue)});
    });
  };
```

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: @PureWare-LegendsOfGaming if you can share entire code, I will take a look.

Comment: The code on my question is the entire code for that component

Comment: I believe the issue is loading the data into state  when there are no items it returns null thus the error